# Sharedpreferences fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I have created two fragments. The second fragment contains multiple  edittexts. 
The SharedPreference works well, but only on the last edittext. For the remaining, it doesn't save anything. At the last, when we write in the edittext, then saving and running again, the app still shows the previous saved date.

```
EditText et;

public TwoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

    et =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.strength_score);
    et =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.strength_modif);
    et =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.strength_tem_scor);
    et =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.strength_tem_modi);


    SharedPreferences setting = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PRESS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    et.setText(setting.getString("value", ""));




    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}

public void onStop( ){
    super.onStop();
    if(et.getText() != null) {
        SharedPreferences setting = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PRESS", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
        editor.putString("value", et.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
     }
   }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you have 4 edittexts with the same name, eventually, you will change the text of the last one only.. ?

Comment: You need to use different objects for different EditText.

Comment: Have you tried using EventBus to communicate between two fragments or between an activity and fragment?

Answer (score 1):

Do like this -

```
EditText et,et1,et2,et3;

public TwoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

    et =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.strength_score);
    et1 =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.strength_modif);
    et2 =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.strength_tem_scor);
    et3 =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.strength_tem_modi);


    SharedPreferences setting = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PRESS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    et.setText(setting.getString("value", ""));
    et1.setText(setting.getString("value1", ""));
    et2.setText(setting.getString("value2", ""));
    et3.setText(setting.getString("value3", ""));




    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}

public void onStop( ){
    super.onStop();
    if(et.getText() != null) {
        SharedPreferences setting = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PRESS", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
        editor.putString("value", et.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("value1", et1.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("value2", et2.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("value3", et3.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
     }
   }
}
```